# Making CMake compile more than 1 source file instead of just the main source file (Similar to .ino of arduino) for code clarity

Tags: c

I've got a piece of code in C in the main.c file of my program which is for embedded ESP 32 in ESP-IDF for context, and I'd like to cut and move some of the code like global variables callback functions definitions etc to other files like init.c, my_functions.c etc without creating a special library with header file and using 3include<lib.h> similar to how you can do it in arduino with ino files.

Is such a thing possible with CMake or ESP-IDF?

Comment: just compile and link the source file?

Comment: how'd you do that with cmake or whatever? I Guess that's what I'm looking for but no direction to how to do it in my frame work.

Comment: add_executable() takes a list of source files

Comment: Are you using cmake already? Or are you asking as someone with no cmake background? You should be able to do this by just creating a target with multiple source files, and cmake will generate a buildsystem that compiles the sources and links them together.